# Удаленное отслеживание содержимого файла

Tags: файлы

Есть файлы, находящиеся в интернете (пользовательские соглашения). Содержимое этих файлов может изменятся, без оповещения.
**Как можно организовать отслеживание их изменений?**

Хочу сделать именно отслеживание содержимого файла. Сделать аналогично GIT, подсвечивать строки измененные/добавленные строки. Но не могу даже представить эту реализацию

Comment: а почему самим гитом не пользоваться то? _ а твое приложение будет просто прослойкой.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал небольшой код, который мониторил бы содержимое HTTP страниц через заданное в настройках время и сверял их. Ну а реализация зависит от потребностей, расширение для Chrome, или утилитка на C# в Forms, или asp.net прилоение с веб мордой, или web api, да много на чём можно это сделать)

Comment: о предметной стороне я пока не думал. Пока на этапе выбора решения. Главная трудность сейчас - выделение частей измененного текста. Я могу найти начало изменений, а вот когда они заканчиваются - проблема

Comment: @Jorik Для примера, можно разбить тексты на массивы слов и те слова которые не встречаются в более раннем тексте подсвечивать. Это навскидку, на самом деле почти в каждом языке есть свои библиотеки по работе со строками и, очень часто, можно сделать всё элегантнее)